# How to know which OpenCV release is stable?

Tags: opencv, software-distribution

Some people wrote check the Github repo of OpenCV, I did but still cannot figure out where is the info is told.

Also, how to know the differences between releases? which section of the documentation?

Comment: in any case, if it is a "release", it is supposed to be stable

Comment: What do you mean if it is a "release" ? you mean as long as it is not Beta nor Alpha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the releases tag you can see the different releases, you can also see which versions are in alpha.

Comment: So I've tags of : Alpha, beta and rc. what is the meaning of each? I think I understand beta means it is under test but what is Alpha and rc?
And if u know how to check the differences between the stable releases? I'm sure it is documented somewhere.

Comment: The release stages goes as following:
Pre-alpha -> Alpha -> Beta -> RC -> RTM -> GA -> Production or live release.

Read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle

Comment: For the difference between releases you have the changelog: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog